# How to fix svg iconmoon not working on codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, icons, codesandbox

I'm currently trying to use icons from iconmoon with 'use' tag in a react small project on codesandbox.
Unfortunately, you won't see any icons on the screen.
Below, the link where the problem occurs, line 45.

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-otrs7

I've already tried to put the svg on public folder and refer to it using  link tag inside head. Still does not work.

```
<use xlinkHref="./img/sprite.svg#icon-react" />
```

I'd like to have the react icon to appear.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I want to precise that I've cloned locally this project and icons appears right but still not on codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for a Vue project on codesandbox.io by putting the SVG in the public directory and then in my template I did this:

```
<img src="icon-name.svg" />
```