# How can I select a specific part in my svg imported with ReactComponent as Logo?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

**Context:**

I have a design file with a Logo that is also the navigation. It's styled like a hexagon grid where each hexagon is a menu which the user can hover and click.

[image]

I exported it with Adobe XD like this: "Export - selected - SVG + Presentation Attributes + Embedded"

Then I imported this whole hexagon as one svg into my projects asset folder. So I have different path's and groups with id's in this svg.

**The question:**

I found out that in react you can use svg like this `import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./myLogo.svg"`

When I do this, how can I then select a specific tile of the hexagon grid with `use` tag? 
I tried it like this:

```
<Logo height="300" width="300">
            <use xlinkHref="CCO_Club" fill="orange" />
        </Logo>
```

But this won't work (also not with `#CCO_CLUB` selector. Fill is doing nothing on that tile. Also when I set a fill on the `<Logo fill="orange" ... />` itself it does nothing.

How can I create this effect? I want to achieve a different color for each tile when I hover on it. But before that I have to know how I even can change the color manually.

Here is the svg (cut off at the end because it's limited to 30.000 lines):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="709" height="679.4" viewBox="0 0 709 679.4" fill="currentColor">
  <g id="Gruppe_118" data-name="Gruppe 118" transform="translate(-84.2 -202)">
    <g id="CCO-cloud" transform="translate(570 411)">
      <path id="Pfad_109" data-name="Pfad 109" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#fff"/>
      <path id="Pfad_110" data-name="Pfad 110" d="M11,76.4,33.9,89.7V191.9L11,205.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_111" data-name="Pfad 111" d="M234.2,205.3l-24.1-13.4V89.7l24.1-13.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_112" data-name="Pfad 112" d="M122.6,12V39.6L33.9,89.7,11,76.5Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_113" data-name="Pfad 113" d="M234.2,76.4,210.1,89.7,122.6,39.6V12Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_114" data-name="Pfad 114" d="M11,205.3l22.9-13.4L122.6,241v28.8Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_115" data-name="Pfad 115" d="M122.6,269.8V241l87.5-49.1,24.1,13.4Z" transform="translate(-11 -12)" fill="#999"/>
      <g id="Gruppe_49" data-name="Gruppe 49" transform="translate(-11 -12)">
        <path id="Pfad_116" data-name="Pfad 116" d="M181.7,109.7a13.931,13.931,0,0,0-4.8-9.5c-1-.7-2-1.4-3-2a14.432,14.432,0,0,0-7.4-1.4l-3.6.8a12.272,12.272,0,0,0-2.6,1.2,23.359,23.359,0,0,0-6.3-8.9c-1.7-1.1-3.4-2.3-5.1-3.4a23.468,23.468,0,0,0-12.2-2.4l-5.9,1.3a25.5,25.5,0,0,0-4.2-4.5c-2.1-1.4-4.2-2.8-6.4-4.3a29.385,29.385,0,0,0-15.4-3c-2.5.5-5,1.1-7.5,1.6a28.581,28.581,0,0,0-12.4,8.4,28.9,28.9,0,0,0-6.5,12.5H77.1c-1.2.3-2.4.5-3.6.8a15.1,15.1,0,0,0-6,4A14.436,14.436,0,0,0,64,111.4a14.158,14.158,0,0,0,4.8,9.6c1,.7,2,1.4,3.1,2.1a14.629,14.629,0,0,0,7.4,1.4c1.2-.3,2.4-.5,3.6-.8a14.722,14.722,0,0,0,2.2-1,29.49,29.49,0,0,0,2.5,2.5c2.1,1.4,4.2,2.9,6.4,4.3a29.385,29.385,0,0,0,15.4,3c2.5-.5,5-1.1,7.5-1.6a29.64,29.64,0,0,0,8.2-4.5c1,.7,2,1.3,3,2a23.468,23.468,0,0,0,12.2,2.4c2-.4,4-.8,6-1.3a23.909,23.909,0,0,0,9.9-6.7,15.583,15.583,0,0,0,1.6-2l.5.5c1,.7,2,1.4,3,2a14.432,14.432,0,0,0,7.4,1.4l3.6-.8a14.105,14.105,0,0,0,5.9-4A12.96,12.96,0,0,0,181.7,109.7Z" fill="#999" opacity="0.6"/>
        <g id="Gruppe_48" data-name="Gruppe 48" opacity="0.6">
          <path id="Pfad_117" data-name="Pfad 117" d="M111.6,82.5c4.8,1.8,9.1,4.3,11.9,8.6A15.781,15.781,0,0,0,113,77.3a15.592,15.592,0,0,0-16.6,4.9A25.423,25.423,0,0,1,111.6,82.5Z" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_118" data-name="Pfad 118" d="M173,114.6a21.29,21.29,0,0,1-15.8-7.3,20.936,20.936,0,0,1-18.5,11.3,20.53,20.53,0,0,1-11.2-3.4,9.97,9.97,0,0,0,6.7-7.6,16.27,16.27,0,0,1-8.7,4.5,15.092,15.092,0,0,1-9.4-1.2,9.926,9.926,0,0,0,7.1,4.6,20.441,20.441,0,0,1-30.8-.2,9.972,9.972,0,0,0,7.7-5.1,15.736,15.736,0,0,1-9.5,1.7,14.871,14.871,0,0,1-8.5-3.9,9.8,9.8,0,0,0,4.9,6.2,22.363,22.363,0,0,1-5.1.7,20.587,20.587,0,0,1-17.1-9.2,13.584,13.584,0,0,0-.7,5.7,14.158,14.158,0,0,0,4.8,9.6c1,.7,2,1.4,3.1,2.1a14.629,14.629,0,0,0,7.4,1.4c1.2-.3,2.4-.5,3.6-.8a14.722,14.722,0,0,0,2.2-1,29.49,29.49,0,0,0,2.5,2.5c2.1,1.4,4.2,2.9,6.4,4.3a29.385,29.385,0,0,0,15.4,3c2.5-.5,5-1.1,7.5-1.6a29.64,29.64,0,0,0,8.2-4.5c1,.7,2,1.3,3,2a23.468,23.468,0,0,0,12.2,2.4c2-.4,4-.8,6-1.3a23.909,23.909,0,0,0,9.9-6.7,15.583,15.583,0,0,0,1.6-2l.5.5c1,.7,2,1.4,3,2a14.432,14.432,0,0,0,7.4,1.4l3.6-.8a14.105,14.105,0,0,0,5.9-4,14.307,14.307,0,0,0,3.4-7.5A17.583,17.583,0,0,1,173,114.6Z" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g id="Gruppe_50" data-name="Gruppe 50" transform="translate(-11 -12)">
        <path id="Pfad_119" data-name="Pfad 119" d="M93.1,184.4c0,5.8-2.6,8.7-7.6,8.7-5.1,0-7.6-2.9-7.6-8.7V160.2c0-5.8,2.5-8.7,7.6-8.7s7.6,2.9,7.6,8.7v5.7H87.2v-5.7c0-1.5-.6-2.3-1.7-2.3h0c-1.1,0-1.7.8-1.7,2.3v24.2c0,1.5.6,2.3,1.7,2.3,1.2,0,1.8-.8,1.8-2.3v-5.7h5.9Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_120" data-name="Pfad 120" d="M97.1,192.5V152.1H103V186h8v6.4Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_121" data-name="Pfad 121" d="M128.9,184.4c0,5.8-2.6,8.7-7.6,8.7-5.1,0-7.6-2.9-7.6-8.7V160.2c0-5.8,2.5-8.7,7.6-8.7s7.6,2.9,7.6,8.7ZM123,160.3c0-1.5-.6-2.3-1.7-2.3h0c-1.1,0-1.7.8-1.7,2.3v24.2c0,1.5.6,2.3,1.7,2.3,1.2,0,1.8-.8,1.8-2.3Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_122" data-name="Pfad 122" d="M148.3,184.5c0,5.8-2.6,8.7-7.6,8.7-5.1,0-7.6-2.9-7.6-8.7V152.2H139v32.3c0,1.5.6,2.3,1.7,2.3,1.2,0,1.8-.8,1.8-2.3V152.2h5.9Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_123" data-name="Pfad 123" d="M152.7,152.2h8.2c4.7,0,7.1,2.9,7.1,8.7v22.9c0,5.8-2.5,8.7-7.4,8.7h-7.9Zm5.9,6.4v27.5h1.8c1.2,0,1.7-.8,1.7-2.3V160.9c0-1.5-.6-2.3-1.7-2.3Z" fill="#999"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="CCO_Club" transform="translate(207 202)">
      <path fill="#fff" id="Pfad_124" data-name="Pfad 124" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" />
      <g id="Gruppe_52" data-name="Gruppe 52" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <g id="Gruppe_51" data-name="Gruppe 51">
          <path id="Pfad_125" data-name="Pfad 125" d="M12.1,77.7,34.8,90.9V192.4L12.1,205.7Z" />
          <path id="Pfad_126" data-name="Pfad 126" d="M233.7,205.7l-24-13.3V90.9l24-13.2Z"  opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_127" data-name="Pfad 127" d="M122.9,13.8V41.2L34.8,90.9,12.1,77.8Z"  opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_128" data-name="Pfad 128" d="M233.7,77.7l-24,13.2L122.9,41.2V13.8Z" />
          <path id="Pfad_129" data-name="Pfad 129" d="M12.1,205.7l22.7-13.3,88.1,48.7v28.6Z"  opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_130" data-name="Pfad 130" d="M122.9,269.7V241.1l86.8-48.7,24,13.3Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <g id="Gruppe_53" data-name="Gruppe 53" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <path id="Pfad_131" data-name="Pfad 131" d="M102,183.9c0,6-2.6,9-7.9,9s-7.9-3-7.9-9v-25c0-6,2.6-9,7.9-9s7.9,3,7.9,9v5.9H95.9v-5.9c0-1.6-.6-2.3-1.8-2.4h0q-1.8,0-1.8,2.4v25q0,2.4,1.8,2.4t1.8-2.4V178H102Z" />
        <path id="Pfad_132" data-name="Pfad 132" d="M106.2,192.3V150.5h6.1v35.1h8.3v6.7Z" />
        <path id="Pfad_133" data-name="Pfad 133" d="M139.3,183.9c0,6-2.6,9-7.9,9s-7.9-3-7.9-9V150.5h6.1v33.4q0,2.4,1.8,2.4t1.8-2.4V150.5h6.1Z" />
        <path id="Pfad_134" data-name="Pfad 134" d="M143.9,150.6h8.4c4.9,0,7.4,3,7.4,9v6.2c0,2.8-.8,4.7-2.5,5.7,1.6,1,2.5,2.9,2.5,5.7v6.2c0,6-2.6,9-7.7,9h-8.1Zm6.1,24.2v10.9h1.8q1.8,0,1.8-2.4v-6.2a2.118,2.118,0,0,0-1.2-2.2,3.808,3.808,0,0,0-1.3-.1Zm0-17.6v10.9h1.2a3.808,3.808,0,0,0,1.3-.1,2.118,2.118,0,0,0,1.2-2.2v-6.2q0-2.4-1.8-2.4Z"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Gruppe_54" data-name="Gruppe 54" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <path id="Pfad_135" data-name="Pfad 135" d="M122.9,130.8H106.4l-2.7,5.6h38.1l-3.6-5.6Z" />
        <path id="Pfad_136" data-name="Pfad 136" d="M122.9,76.3H85.3v44.4h75.2V76.3Z" />
        <path id="Pfad_137" data-name="Pfad 137" d="M127.9,129.8v-8.2H117.4v8.2h10.5Z" />
      </g>
      <path id="Pfad_138" data-name="Pfad 138" d="M155.4,116.9h-65V80.2h65Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#fff"/>
    </g>
    <g id="CCO_Gaming" transform="translate(449 624)">
      <path id="Pfad_139" data-name="Pfad 139" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#fff"/>
      <path id="Pfad_140" data-name="Pfad 140" d="M12.1,77.7,34.8,90.9V192.4L12.1,205.7Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_141" data-name="Pfad 141" d="M233.7,205.7l-24-13.3V90.9l24-13.2Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_142" data-name="Pfad 142" d="M122.9,13.8V41.2L34.8,90.9,12.1,77.8Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_143" data-name="Pfad 143" d="M233.7,77.7l-24,13.2L122.9,41.2V13.8Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_144" data-name="Pfad 144" d="M12.1,205.7l22.7-13.3,88.1,48.7v28.6Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_145" data-name="Pfad 145" d="M122.9,269.7V241.1l86.8-48.7,24,13.3Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#999"/>
      <g id="Gruppe_55" data-name="Gruppe 55" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <path id="Pfad_146" data-name="Pfad 146" d="M78.7,174.6h6.8v12.3c0,4.6-2.3,7-7,7-4.6,0-7-2.3-7-7V167.5c0-4.6,2.3-7,7-7,4.6,0,7,2.3,7,7v4.6H80.1v-4.6c0-1.2-.5-1.8-1.6-1.8h0c-1,0-1.6.6-1.6,1.8v19.4c0,1.2.5,1.8,1.6,1.8s1.6-.6,1.6-1.8v-7.1H78.7Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_147" data-name="Pfad 147" d="M102.9,183.1l1.5,10.2H99l-.9-5.9h-4l-.9,5.9H87.8l1.5-10.1,3.3-18.3h7Zm-5.4-.2-1.3-8.6-1.3,8.6Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_148" data-name="Pfad 148" d="M117.6,183.8l5-18.8h5.3v28.4h-5.2V180.3l-3.2,13.1h-3.8l-3.3-13.2v13.2h-5.2V165h5.3Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_149" data-name="Pfad 149" d="M132.1,164.9h5.4v28.4h-5.4Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_150" data-name="Pfad 150" d="M141.7,164.9H147l3.6,14v-14h5v28.4h-5.3l-3.4-13.6v13.6h-5.2V164.9Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_151" data-name="Pfad 151" d="M166.8,176.9h6.7v10.8c0,4.1-2.3,6.1-7,6.1-4.6,0-7-2-7-6.1v-17c0-4.1,2.3-6.1,7-6.1,4.6,0,7,2,7,6.1v4h-5.4v-4a1.389,1.389,0,0,0-1.6-1.6h0a1.427,1.427,0,0,0-1.6,1.6v17a1.6,1.6,0,0,0,3.2,0v-6.2h-1.3Z" fill="#999"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Gruppe_89" data-name="Gruppe 89" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <g id="Gruppe_58" data-name="Gruppe 58">
          <g id="Gruppe_57" data-name="Gruppe 57">
            <g id="Gruppe_56" data-name="Gruppe 56">
              <path id="Pfad_152" data-name="Pfad 152" d="M93.4,138.4H87.8a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5v-6.8H80.7a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5V125a.472.472,0,0,1,.5-.5h6.6v-6.8a.472.472,0,0,1,.5-.5h5.6a.472.472,0,0,1,.5.5v6.8h6.9a.472.472,0,0,1,.5.5v5.6a.472.472,0,0,1-.5.5H93.9v6.8A.472.472,0,0,1,93.4,138.4Zm-5.2-.9h4.7v-6.8a.472.472,0,0,1,.5-.5h6.9v-4.7H93.4a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5v-6.8H88.2V125a.472.472,0,0,1-.5.5H81.1v4.7h6.6a.472.472,0,0,1,.5.5Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_61" data-name="Gruppe 61">
          <g id="Gruppe_60" data-name="Gruppe 60">
            <g id="Gruppe_59" data-name="Gruppe 59">
              <path id="Pfad_153" data-name="Pfad 153" d="M150.5,149.5a22.261,22.261,0,0,1-17.9-9H109.1a22.383,22.383,0,1,1-17.9-35.8c.9,0,1.8.1,2.8.2h53.8a24.519,24.519,0,0,1,2.7-.2,22.4,22.4,0,0,1,0,44.8Zm-41.6-9.9h24a.758.758,0,0,1,.4.2,21.4,21.4,0,1,0,17.3-34,26.455,26.455,0,0,0-2.7.2H94c-1-.1-1.9-.2-2.7-.2a21.4,21.4,0,1,0,17.3,34C108.6,139.6,108.7,139.6,108.9,139.6Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_64" data-name="Gruppe 64">
          <g id="Gruppe_63" data-name="Gruppe 63">
            <g id="Gruppe_62" data-name="Gruppe 62">
              <path id="Pfad_154" data-name="Pfad 154" d="M150.7,143.9a16.8,16.8,0,1,1,16.8-16.8A16.772,16.772,0,0,1,150.7,143.9Zm0-32.6a15.9,15.9,0,1,0,15.9,15.9A15.94,15.94,0,0,0,150.7,111.3Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_67" data-name="Gruppe 67">
          <g id="Gruppe_66" data-name="Gruppe 66">
            <g id="Gruppe_65" data-name="Gruppe 65">
              <path id="Pfad_155" data-name="Pfad 155" d="M150.8,124.4a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,0-7,3.543,3.543,0,0,1,3.5,3.5A3.478,3.478,0,0,1,150.8,124.4Zm0-6.1a2.6,2.6,0,1,0,2.6,2.6A2.582,2.582,0,0,0,150.8,118.3Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_70" data-name="Gruppe 70">
          <g id="Gruppe_69" data-name="Gruppe 69">
            <g id="Gruppe_68" data-name="Gruppe 68">
              <path id="Pfad_156" data-name="Pfad 156" d="M158.1,131.1a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,0-7,3.543,3.543,0,0,1,3.5,3.5A3.478,3.478,0,0,1,158.1,131.1Zm0-6.1a2.6,2.6,0,1,0,2.6,2.6A2.647,2.647,0,0,0,158.1,125Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_73" data-name="Gruppe 73">
          <g id="Gruppe_72" data-name="Gruppe 72">
            <g id="Gruppe_71" data-name="Gruppe 71">
              <path id="Pfad_157" data-name="Pfad 157" d="M144.1,131.2a3.5,3.5,0,1,1,3.5-3.5A3.417,3.417,0,0,1,144.1,131.2Zm0-6.1a2.6,2.6,0,1,0,2.6,2.6A2.522,2.522,0,0,0,144.1,125.1Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_76" data-name="Gruppe 76">
          <g id="Gruppe_75" data-name="Gruppe 75">
            <g id="Gruppe_74" data-name="Gruppe 74">
              <path id="Pfad_158" data-name="Pfad 158" d="M151.2,138.2a3.5,3.5,0,1,1,3.5-3.5A3.543,3.543,0,0,1,151.2,138.2Zm0-6.2a2.6,2.6,0,1,0,2.6,2.6A2.647,2.647,0,0,0,151.2,132Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_79" data-name="Gruppe 79">
          <g id="Gruppe_78" data-name="Gruppe 78">
            <g id="Gruppe_77" data-name="Gruppe 77">
              <path id="Pfad_159" data-name="Pfad 159" d="M119.9,106h-.2c-.1-.1-14.2-5.8-13.5-17.9.6-10.5,6.3-12.2,12.8-14.2,1.1-.3,2.2-.7,3.4-1.1a10.4,10.4,0,0,0,6.7-11,7.159,7.159,0,0,0-7-6.6c-.3,0-.5-.2-.4-.5,0-.3.3-.4.5-.4a8.273,8.273,0,0,1,7.9,7.4,11.3,11.3,0,0,1-7.3,12c-1.2.4-2.3.7-3.4,1.1-6.4,1.9-11.5,3.5-12.1,13.4-.7,11.4,12.8,16.9,12.9,16.9.2.1.4.4.3.6A1.546,1.546,0,0,1,119.9,106Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_82" data-name="Gruppe 82">
          <g id="Gruppe_81" data-name="Gruppe 81">
            <g id="Gruppe_80" data-name="Gruppe 80">
              <path id="Pfad_160" data-name="Pfad 160" d="M117,111.8a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5V106a.5.5,0,0,1,1,0v5.3A.472.472,0,0,1,117,111.8Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_85" data-name="Gruppe 85">
          <g id="Gruppe_84" data-name="Gruppe 84">
            <g id="Gruppe_83" data-name="Gruppe 83">
              <path id="Pfad_161" data-name="Pfad 161" d="M120,111.8a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5V106a.5.5,0,0,1,1,0v5.3A.472.472,0,0,1,120,111.8Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_88" data-name="Gruppe 88">
          <g id="Gruppe_87" data-name="Gruppe 87">
            <g id="Gruppe_86" data-name="Gruppe 86">
              <path id="Pfad_162" data-name="Pfad 162" d="M123,111.8a.472.472,0,0,1-.5-.5V106a.5.5,0,0,1,1,0v5.3A.472.472,0,0,1,123,111.8Z" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="CCO_Logo" transform="translate(328 412)">
      <path id="Pfad_163" data-name="Pfad 163" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)" fill="#fff"/>
      <g id="Gruppe_92" data-name="Gruppe 92" transform="translate(-12.1 -13.8)">
        <g id="Gruppe_90" data-name="Gruppe 90">
          <path id="Pfad_164" data-name="Pfad 164" d="M12.1,77.7,34.8,90.9V192.3L12.1,205.7Z" fill="#008d36"/>
          <path id="Pfad_165" data-name="Pfad 165" d="M233.7,205.7l-24-13.3V90.9l24-13.2Z" fill="#008d36" opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_166" data-name="Pfad 166" d="M122.9,13.8V41.2L34.8,90.9,12.1,77.8Z" fill="#008d36" opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_167" data-name="Pfad 167" d="M233.7,77.7l-24,13.2L122.9,41.2V13.8Z" fill="#008d36"/>
          <path id="Pfad_168" data-name="Pfad 168" d="M12.1,205.7l22.7-13.4,88.1,48.8v28.6Z" fill="#008d36" opacity="0.8"/>
          <path id="Pfad_169" data-name="Pfad 169" d="M122.9,269.7V241.1l86.8-48.8,24,13.4Z" fill="#008d36"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Gruppe_91" data-name="Gruppe 91">
          <path id="Pfad_170" data-name="Pfad 170" d="M89.7,164.8c0,11.1-7.4,16.6-22.3,16.7-14.8,0-22.3-5.6-22.3-16.7V118.6c0-11.1,7.4-16.6,22.3-16.6s22.3,5.5,22.3,16.6v10.9H72.5V118.6c0-2.9-1.7-4.3-5.1-4.4h-.1c-3.3,0-5,1.5-5,4.4v46.2c0,2.9,1.7,4.4,5.1,4.4s5.1-1.4,5.1-4.4V153.9H89.7Z" fill="#008d36"/>
          <path id="Pfad_171" data-name="Pfad 171" d="M145.2,164.8c0,11.1-7.4,16.6-22.3,16.7-14.8,0-22.3-5.6-22.3-16.7V118.6c0-11.1,7.4-16.6,22.3-16.6s22.3,5.5,22.3,16.6v10.9H128V118.6c0-2.9-1.7-4.3-5.1-4.4h-.1c-3.3,0-5,1.5-5,4.4v46.2c0,2.9,1.7,4.4,5.1,4.4s5.1-1.4,5.1-4.4V153.9h17.2v10.9Z" fill="#008d36"/>
          <path id="Pfad_172" data-name="Pfad 172" d="M200.6,164.8c0,11.1-7.4,16.6-22.3,16.7-14.8,0-22.3-5.6-22.3-16.7V118.6c0-11.1,7.4-16.6,22.3-16.6s22.3,5.5,22.3,16.6v46.2Zm-17.2-46.2c0-2.9-1.7-4.3-5.1-4.4h-.1c-3.3,0-5,1.5-5,4.4v46.2c0,2.9,1.7,4.4,5.1,4.4s5.1-1.4,5.1-4.4V118.6Z" fill="#008d36"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="CCO_rendering" transform="translate(205 623)">
      <path id="Pfad_173" data-name="Pfad 173" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#fff"/>
      <path id="Pfad_174" data-name="Pfad 174" d="M11,75.8,34,89.1V191.6L11,205.1Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_175" data-name="Pfad 175" d="M234.8,205.1l-24.3-13.5V89.1l24.3-13.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_176" data-name="Pfad 176" d="M122.9,11.3V38.9L34,89.1,11,75.9Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_177" data-name="Pfad 177" d="M234.8,75.9,210.5,89.1,122.9,38.9V11.3Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_178" data-name="Pfad 178" d="M11,205.1l23-13.5,88.9,49.2v28.9Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999" opacity="0.8"/>
      <path id="Pfad_179" data-name="Pfad 179" d="M122.9,269.7V240.8l87.6-49.2,24.3,13.5Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_180" data-name="Pfad 180" d="M105.6,55" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999"/>
      <path id="Pfad_181" data-name="Pfad 181" d="M93.5,122.7l.1-33.6,29.1-16.6,29,16.9-.1,33.5-29.1,16.7Z" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)" fill="#999"/>
      <line id="Linie_1" data-name="Linie 1" x1="0.6" y2="35.1" transform="translate(82 77.8)" fill="none"/>
      <line id="Linie_2" data-name="Linie 2" x2="32.5" y2="19.4" transform="translate(79.5 75.9)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line id="Linie_3" data-name="Linie 3" x1="28.7" y2="16.6" transform="translate(112 78.1)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line id="Linie_4" data-name="Linie 4" x1="0.1" y2="37.2" transform="translate(111.5 94.7)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
      <g id="Gruppe_93" data-name="Gruppe 93" transform="translate(-11 -11.3)">
        <path id="Pfad_182" data-name="Pfad 182" d="M49.6,158.6h7.1c4.4,0,6.6,2.4,6.6,7.1v4.8c0,3-1.2,4.9-3.6,5.8l5.2,15.1H59l-3.7-14.1H55v14.1H49.6Zm5.4,5.2v8.6h.7a2.532,2.532,0,0,0,1.1-.1,1.728,1.728,0,0,0,1-1.8v-4.8c0-1.2-.5-1.9-1.6-1.9Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_183" data-name="Pfad 183" d="M67.6,158.6H80.4v5.2H73v8.6h6.3v5.3H73v8.6h7.4v5.2H67.6Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_184" data-name="Pfad 184" d="M83.8,158.6h5.4l3.6,16.2V158.6h5.1v32.8H92.5L89,175.7v15.7H83.7Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_185" data-name="Pfad 185" d="M102.2,158.6h7.5c4.4,0,6.6,2.4,6.6,7.1v18.6c0,4.7-2.3,7.1-6.9,7.1h-7.3Zm5.5,5.2v22.4h1.6c1.1,0,1.6-.6,1.6-1.8V165.8c0-1.2-.5-1.9-1.6-1.9l-1.6-.1Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_186" data-name="Pfad 186" d="M120.2,158.6H133v5.2h-7.4v8.6h6.3v5.3h-6.3v8.6H133v5.2H120.2Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_187" data-name="Pfad 187" d="M136.5,158.6h7.1c4.4,0,6.6,2.4,6.6,7.1v4.8c0,3-1.2,4.9-3.6,5.8l5.2,15.1h-5.9l-3.7-14.1h-.3v14.1h-5.4Zm5.4,5.2v8.6h.7a2.532,2.532,0,0,0,1.1-.1,1.728,1.728,0,0,0,1-1.8v-4.8c0-1.2-.5-1.9-1.6-1.9Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_188" data-name="Pfad 188" d="M154.6,158.6H160v32.8h-5.4Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_189" data-name="Pfad 189" d="M164.4,158.6h5.4l3.6,16.2V158.6h5.1v32.8h-5.4l-3.5-15.7v15.7h-5.3Z" fill="#999"/>
        <path id="Pfad_190" data-name="Pfad 190" d="M189.7,172.5h6.8V185c0,4.7-2.4,7.1-7.1,7.1s-7-2.4-7-7.1V165.3c0-4.7,2.4-7.1,7.1-7.1s7.1,2.4,7.1,7.1V170h-5.4v-4.7c0-1.2-.5-1.9-1.6-1.9h0c-1.1,0-1.6.6-1.6,1.9V185c0,1.2.5,1.8,1.6,1.8s1.6-.6,1.6-1.8v-7.2h-1.4v-5.3Z" fill="#999"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="CMO-members" transform="translate(449 203)" style="isolation: isolate">
      <path id="Pfad_191" data-name="Pfad 191" d="M19.7,83.6l103-59,97.8,59V197.2l-97.6,58L22.3,198.3Z" transform="translate(-10.7 -11.1)" fill="#fff"/>
      <g id="Gruppe_94" data-name="Gruppe 94" transform="translate(-10.7 -11.1)">
        <path id="Pfad_192" data-name="Pfad 192" d="M131.8,81.3c-.1-.1-.3-.1-.4-.2a10.942,10.942,0,1,0-19.3-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the SVG inline, which is so much easier to have interaction with rather than trying to use it as an asset.

Here's a codepen demo: https://codepen.io/Wolfmans55/pen/ZEGLMwG

CSS

```
svg {
  /* sizing it down just so it's not massive */
  /* you can make an svg responsive by keeping its viewBox attribute */
  /* and removing the width and height attributes */
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
}

/* cloud hover */
svg .cloud:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .cloud:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: red;
}

/* members hover */
svg .members:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .members:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: orange;
}

/* club hover */
svg .club:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .club:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: yellow;
}

/* security hover */
svg .security:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .security:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: green;
}

/* rendering hover */
svg .rendering:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .rendering:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: blue;
}

/* gaming hover */
svg .gaming:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .gaming:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: indigo;
}

/* cco hover */
svg .cco:hover path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0),
svg .cco:focus path[class^="prefix__st"]:not(.prefix__st0) {
  fill: violet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill alone won't work as the tiles are made of several paths, each with a fill already defined. One solution would be to define a [color filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix) in the svg:

```
 <filter id="colorize">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" 
            type="matrix"
            values="1 0 0 0 0
                    1 1 0 0 0
                    0 0 1 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
```

And then use it from a css class/any React styling method. e.g.

```
#CCO-cloud:hover {
  filter: url(#colorize);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-goodall-s3j07

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. But how can I then chose custom colors like my design spec? I tried this: `#CCO_Club:hover path:not(.st0) {
  fill: orange;
}` but it makes the whole tile orange and now just the things I want to have orange :D

Comment: I found a solution and recreated it on codesandbox. Unfortunately it doesn't look like in my project. On Codesandbox tiles are black and have color when hovered. On my project it looks correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-voice-kltrr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
It also seems that it has no depth or conture. Weird. Seems like a bug with Codesandbox - like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544523/how-to-fix-svg-iconmoon-not-working-on-codesandbox